# Listening for events on server using TCP IP Server/Client model

Tags: sockets, tcp, server, ip, client

I would like to create a TCP IP listener on my windows server 2012 to listen for certain events coming from a web based client.  When I receive these events, I will perform actions on the server and then send the response back to the client.

I was going to base this on the following server client models found here...

Server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx
Client: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

I am interested to know if this is a good approach to solve this problem, or if there are any other common ways to achieve the same thing, perhaps a more modern approach which I can compare with. Are there any pros and cons between the different approaches?

Comment: Define 'best' and 'better'. Too broad.

Comment: I have updated - I would really just like to know about other approaches which I could compare.